# Chrome extension with angular: cannot run test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, google-chrome-extension, karma-jasmine, e2e

I have a chrome extension that I need to add the tests to, I'm using karma + jazmine and sinon-chrome to mock up the Chrome API. Every time I run the Karma tests, it does them as if it were a web page and some functionalities are out of Karma's scope, so the tests fail. I would like to know if there are better options to do unit tests and e2e tests for chrome extensions